# Can I develop chrome extension using native react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-extension

I am very new to **reactjs** and **native react**. I need some suggestions and well-explained tutorial links about these. My question is can I develop web google chrome extension using **native react**? Can this extension will run on all platforms? If yes, then how? If no, then what is an alternative to this? I want to build platform independent web google chrome extension using **native react**. Please provide me some simple tutorial links for this.

Comment: Extensions can only run JavaScript code, which in turn can run WebAssembly. Extensions can launch external utilities written in any language via nativeMessaging API.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you provide any documentation or tutorial links?

Comment: You should be able to find those trivially in Google search or a similar site.